# Create executable application in linux

Tags: linux

I wanna know how to create executable application in linux just like .exe file in windows.
    most of  you have used/seen "Pidgin IM" in linux on click of that it will open the window where you can see your buddies and more similar to gnome-caculator.
               i want to create the same executable file for my application.

thank you adavnce.

Comment: Could you further clarify your question? Is your question about wanting to know how to create a desktop/"Start menu" shortcut which the users could click on?

Answer (score 5):

The most common way to create executables is to use a compiler. (Just like on windows.) The GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) may already be installed on your Linux system, see if you can find it with:

```
$ which gcc
```

or

```
$ gcc --help
```

If not, you'll have to install it. It has man pages (`man gcc`), info pages (`info gcc`), and an [online manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).

Note the `gcc` command itself is the C compiler part, there's `g++` for C++ and others for other languages (though you have considerable control through command line options).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a framework such as [Qt](http://qtsoftware.com) or [WxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org). Both these frameworks allow you to create windowed GUI applications for Linux (and Windows and Mac OS X).

Comment: Those are GUIs. He's looking for something like .deb

Answer (score 1):

Hm, a few steps:

You first have to write your program. You could write it in C, C++, Python, Java, or anything. If you want the program to have a GUI, rather than just being command-line based, then you have to write code that paints windows, buttons, etc.

After doing that, you'll have an executable. In Linux, in contrast to Windows, executable files don't have a ".exe" suffix. Were you to open a terminal, you could just type in "pidgin" and the program would run.

Finally, to create the desktop/menu shortuct, that is specific to the GUI environment. In gnome, you can right-click on the desktop, select "Create Launcher", and follow the menu to select the executable file you have created - similarly to what you do in Windows.

Not sure if this is what you were asking about, but I hope that is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of it depends on which language you are using to write the program, if you are using a scripting language like bash, python of php you need to make sure the first line of the script tells what interpreter to use:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

This tells the machine to look for the python executable to interpret the rest of the script. You can do the same thing with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env php
```

or

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

the other thing you need to remember is to change the permissions to make the script/program executable:

```
chmod 755 myscript.py
```